# Enabling behavior based on bit values

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have a series of behaviors I want to enable/disable based on bit values. For example, the status of Behavior "A" is 0 or 1, Behavior "B" is 0 or 2, Behavior "C" is 0 or 4, etc. If the value of the variable containing the status is "5", I know Behavior "A" and "C" are enabled. "B" is not. My program should then toggle on A & C.

I'm not sure what this is called so hopefully someone here can give me a name and shove me in the right direction. How do I programmatically create the list of enabled functions based on the status variable? There may be 20-30 behaviors i want to control in this manner. Too many to manage manually.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a [BitVector32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.bitvector32.aspx) or [BitArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray.aspx). They abstract away bit manipulation from you.

If you want to manipulate individual bits in an `int` variable directly, you can use bitwise operators:

#### Check whether i-th bit is set or not:

```
bool isSet = (variable & (1 << i)) != 0;
```

#### Set i-th bit:

```
variable |= (1 << i);
```

#### Reset i-th bit:

```
variable &= ~(1 << i);
```

#### Toggle i-th bit:

```
variable ^= (1 << i);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example:

```
class DispatchTable
{
    readonly Action[] _actions;

    public DispatchTable(params Action[] actions)
    {
        _actions = actions;
    }

    public void Execute(ulong actionsMask)
    {
        for (int bitIx = 0; bitIx < _actions.Length && actionsMask != 0; bitIx++, actionsMask >>= 1)
        {
            if ((actionsMask & 0x01) != 0)
                _actions[bitIx]();
        }           
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DispatchTable t = new DispatchTable(
            delegate() { Console.WriteLine(1); },
            delegate() { Console.WriteLine(2); },
            delegate() { Console.WriteLine(3); }
        );

        t.Execute(0x04);
        t.Execute(0x02);
        t.Execute(0x01);
        t.Execute(0x0F);
    }
}
```